# Local package dependency to R data.table ":="

Tags: r, data.table, dependencies, r-package

I have a local R package and some functions are operating with data.table operations. When I install package, it installs the data.table since it is a dependent. However, I couldn't figure out this part in the package.

This one is working in the function:

```
dt=data.table::as.data.table(dt)
```

so it converts dt to a data.table

This one is not working

```
dt[SuperDummyDate == '',SuperDummyDate := NA]
```

the package can't find that ":=" is a datatable function. since it is in [], I can't add data.table::..

I tried require(data.table) within the function, but still didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-importing.html? Have you defined `.datatable.aware=TRUE` somewhere in the package itself? (The latter should only be required if you use it in `Suggests:` instead of `Imports:`, but it doesn't hurt to have it anyway.

Comment: I have added import(data.table) in the namespace and it worked. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` should be imported in the `NAMESPACE` file of the package :

```
import(data.table)
```

With [Roxygen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html), you could require this import in the function header, it will be automatically added to `NAMESPACE`:

```
#' Your function title & description
#'
#' @parameter data
#' @import data.table
#'
DTfunction <- function(data) {
  data[,newcol:=.SD[,1]]
}
```

Test after loading the function:

```
DTfunction(as.data.table(mtcars[,1:2]))

      mpg   cyl newcol
    <num> <num>  <num>
 1:  21.0     6   21.0
 2:  21.0     6   21.0
 3:  22.8     4   22.8
 4:  21.4     6   21.4
...
```

Comment: I have added import(data.table) into namespace and worked. thank you very much!